# Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2011

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2012](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3957/community-promotion-ads-2012)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool desktop apps
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://meta.superuser.com/ads/display/2164).

Comment: Like commented [on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74983/advertising-sidebar-1h-2011#comments-74983): sane browsers do NOT show `alt` text on mouseover. And even when shown by non-compliant browsers, `alt` should describe what is missing, not some tag line. So maybe it should be labeled *"The text used on browsers that don't support images (like by readers used by visually impaired)"*. If a mouseover is wanted too, then besides the `alt` attribute the `title` should be specified as well, after the image or link URL. Like: `[1]: http://image-url "Tagline to show on mouseover"`

Comment: I was tempted to suggest PDF Creator, but given its default installation of the Yahoo! toolbar nowadays, I don't. Any other PDF printer, anyone?

Comment: @Arjan CutePDF!

Comment: Hmmm, @Sathya: *[Requires PS2PDF converter such as Ghostscript](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp)* — which is simply bundled with [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/). Really too bad they started to install that Yahoo! thingy by default. (Though I do think one is prompted for that during installation; haven't installed it for a while.)

Comment: oh, my bad then @Arjan

Comment: +1. Cool idea, these ads.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas: Mouse-overs are not working for images that are linkified, can you look into this? I'm using Chrome 11.0.696.0 dev but I suspect this is also the case for older versions. Should we use Arjan's syntax?

Comment: @TomWij - mouse-overs don't show in the posts below however when the ad is rendered the ALT text is used as the title.  We wanted to keep the template syntax simple.

Comment: @Arjan I use OpenOffice.org for making PDF files :)

Comment: Sure, @The, that is indeed the best option (like to get clickable links and TOCs) when doing word processing. (And I am on a Mac, which has great PDF support anyhow; still OpenOffice.org's built-in export is superior to that.)

Comment: It's time for `2H 2011`, isn't it?

Comment: If someone feels like posting [TotalMounter](http://reboot.pro/15170/), that'd be great. I can't find a new image so I can't do it unfortunately, but it's an awesome product apparently.

Comment: What happened to the ad for Chrome?

Comment: @oKtosiTe nhinkle deleted it and commented: *In light of discussion about what constitutes an appropriate community ad, with respect to companies that can afford to purchase advertising, I am deleting this ad for the time being. – nhinkle♦*

Comment: It would seem Ubuntu walks a fine line then. @Daniel Beck

Comment: @oKtosiTe Just related that comment to the deleted answer as you're unable to see it due to rep requirement. Maybe advertising is so expensive that Canonical cannot afford it?

Comment: @GraceNote These ads are still shown. Is this intended?

Answer (score 110):

[image: 7zip, beyond zip]

Comment: And: *gui and command line*, and *multi platform*?

Comment: Really, why is anyone still using WinRAR?

Comment: @ultrasawblade because you can dragdrop from winrar into an application, and any changes to that document is automatically pulled back into the archive. Couldn't get 7zip to do that

Comment: Really, Winrar era needs to stop

Comment: people don't wanna learn new stuff, everyone is lazy like me ! 7zip UI is not that user friendly other then that its awesome and has better compression on its own format but again its much more less common then rar.

Comment: 7-zip is good but ugly. Hence WinRAR.

Comment: [The King (of compression)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRAR) is dead, long live [the King (of compression)](http://www.7-zip.org/)! All hail 7-zip!

Comment: @ultrasawblade: Better shell integration.

Comment: If your _only_ complaint about 7zip is that it's ugly, there is a skinning program you can use. @Meh

Comment: @Lord: Well don't leave me hanging, what's the skinning program? :)

Comment: Sorry, I was having a hard time finding it. It's because I was searching for "skin" and not "theme." Anyways see [this blog post](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/03/31/7-zip-theme-manager/). @Meh

Comment: @Lord: Ooh nice, I see it's a (relatively) new program! :) I'll try it out, thanks! :)

Comment: Ahhhh but there's still something missing: **No context menu icons!** Believe it or not, that can actually be a dealmaker/[breaker](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/860418-7zip-context-menu-icons/) in these situations. :\

Answer (score 93):

[image: VideoLAN Player. It's free and plays everything.]

Comment: The logo is awesome!

Comment: It always reminds me of Kraftwerk - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:K1-D-front.jpg

Comment: VLC on Ubuntu (Linux) *Doesn't* play *all* DVD-Videos. But on the same machine booted into Windows, VLC does: http://superuser.com/questions/199963/ubuntu-10-x-playing-all-dvd-videos-via-a-simple-gui-app-precise-instructions-re

Comment: There should be some mention of "media" in the ad. "Plays everything? Does it also play the piano? Does it play games?" Without "media" it's kinda vague.

Comment: It's actually even called the »VLC *Media* Player«, so technically the ad is a bit wrong.

Answer (score 77):

[image: ubuntu, Linux for human beings]

Comment: IMHO the tagline is terrible. Most people in the target don't know or care about "Linux".

Comment: It is the official tagline .

Answer (score 58):

[image: Microsoft Process Explorer -- find out what's running on your PC, and why]

Comment: +1 - LOVE this.... I am recommending it all the time! (And Autoruns... I will try to make one a little later)

Comment: While its a great program, I much prefer the open source Process Hacker http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This is a great tool if you ever need to find which process has an open handle on a file.

Answer (score 58):

[image: Free virtualisation for the masses]

Comment: s/s/z :P @Blood

Comment: Virtualization I thought?

Comment: @nhinkle depends, s is British English, z is American.  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11788/virtualisation-vs-virtualization

Comment: We do have an international community here, but given that Stack Exchange is an American company, I personally think it should be with a `z`.

Comment: I'd prefer to take into consideration the way it's spelled on the [VirtualBox website](http://www.virtualbox.org/). "_VirtualBox is a powerful x86 and AMD64/Intel64 **virtualization** product [...]_" @nhinkle, BloodPhilia

Comment: Guys, why does it matter so much if it's *s* or *z* in this case?

Comment: Maybe @Cawaz iz right.

Comment: @Sathya: I finally learned about sed (i.e. I'm finally nerdy enough) to "get" what you meant. Lol. :)

Comment: @Sathya: Speaking of which, I think you missed a trailing slash...

Comment: The name "VirtualBox" should be more prominent. If I weren't already a user, I wouldn't even realize that that's the name of the software.

Answer (score 58):

[image: Firefox - Made to make the Web a better place.]

Comment: If there are any suggestions, I'll be happy to take them into consideration. This was made with [the Firefox 3.6 icon set](http://u.tknet.nl/grANtU). Source `xcf` (GIMP image file) available [here](http://u.tknet.nl/fCOxZA).

Comment: Might be a good idea to mention Firefox 4's imminent release

Comment: I will certainly consider adding in a **4** once the release has been made. @YiJiang

Comment: Might be a good idea to mention Firefox 5's imminent release... er, 6's -- er, 7's... er...

Comment: Indeed. Instead of keeping up with their new rapid release cycle, I think we're better off removing all references to a specific version altogether. At least for now. @Mehrdad

Comment: @oktosite: Just write "Firefox 17" and it'll be correct in no time!

Comment: .... er, 8's...

Comment: ... er, 10's...

Answer (score 53):

[image: community blog for Super Users, by Super Users]

Comment: I really like this though can you flip Super User over and leave it horizontal over the "community blog"

Comment: Nice one @BloodPhilia

Answer (score 52):

[image: Super User members can vote on Community Ads to be displayed here. Submit yours today!]

Comment: this is cool @nhinkle, I like this

Comment: omg meta! so meta!

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Yes, but it's actually useful, explaining to people what's going on.

Answer (score 46):

[image: GIMP]

Comment: That looks slick @Alaukik!

Comment: Should say what it is. The only hint is the paintbrush, and that looks like a cigarette!

Answer (score 42):

[image: Synergy]

Comment: This is one of the best tools on the list. for people who use more then one computer next each other.

Comment: "What does KM mean?"

Comment: Keyboard, Mouse @slhck. a KVM switch is a piece of hardware that switches the keyboard/mouse/video from one computer to the other, so this is a software solution that switches the keyboard/mouse from one computer to the other.

Comment: @studiohack *I* personally know, I've used Synergy before :P I just put it under quotation marks to imply that people might wonder what it is when looking at the app.

Answer (score 39):

[image: Paint.Net - Get it now!]

Comment: I like this ad; the only problem I have with it is that saying "it costs a lot less" might imply that it does cost _something_, just less. I would consider changing it to say "(and it's free, too)" or something like that

Comment: I'd suggest you use an image you actually have permission to use. [This one belongs to Getty Images](http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/91534208), apparently.

Comment: @Joey I didn't realise that, I just found it via Google image search, I'll replace it as soon as I can.

Comment: Now with a legal image! [Background photograph](http://www.flickr.com/photos/easylocum/2921542434/) by Flickr user [Easylocum](http://www.flickr.com/photos/easylocum/). Original photo licensed as [CC BY 2.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/deed.en).

Comment: Paint.net is one of my favorite Windows apps. Very polished and excellent.

Comment: I think we need to replace the image...

Comment: What do you want to replace it with? Or do you have any ideas for updates?

Comment: Well, since the image was removed from imgur.com, perhaps just re-add the old image?

Comment: The link has died again.

Comment: I currently have the image for this but do not believe there is reason to a) bump this topic unnecessarily or b) post this to the 2012 Community Ads as it got quite a bit of airtime last year.  Let me know if you feel differently.

Answer (score 32):

[image: Read the Super User Community Blog's guide to choosing a laptop for college.]

Answer (score 30):

[image: Wireshark • Go deep.]

Comment: Nice-looking and descriptive, and a useful program.

Comment: Always thought WS's tagline to be... well.. dubious at least...

Comment: Perfect for [shark week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shark_Week)!

Comment: "Go deep." ... Hmm..

Answer (score 28):

[image: Get Libreoffice, Liberate your Office]

Comment: The icon is too generic.

Comment: @LaC: agree. Also, the font for the subtitle is messed up.

Answer (score 27):

[image: Empower the world's poorest children through education]

Comment: Who needs shoes when you can have a laptop.

Comment: Education is a fundamental right that these children are sadly not given easy access to. OLPC aims to help them in that regard at least @slo

Comment: I agree, it is worthwhile. I was being facetious.

Answer (score 26):

[image: America's online censorship bill could close down sites like Stack Exchange. Click here to learn more about how SOPA impacts you, regardless of where you live.]

Comment: [I am not sure how people outside US can help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114010/133693)

Comment: @Sathya are you asking or providing the link for reference?

Comment: bit of both actually.

Comment: @Sathya one thing people abroad can do is contact American elected officials and tell them that if this legislation passes, it will cause foreign customers to stop using American web services, which are responsible for a significant portion of the US economy. Widescale censorship in the US will lead customers from overseas to use alternative products, which will negatively impact US businesses. Additionally, you can help educate American friends and relatives, who can influence this more directly via their elected officials.

Comment: Minor annoyance: I saw this ad on the Super User homepage, but when I moved the mouse pointer to the red text that says "Click here to learn why this matters", a black bar slid up with the "16 votes - comment - stats" text preventing me from clicking the red text. Although I know where to click instead, it seems wrong to have text inviting you to "click here" that you can't actually click.

Comment: Thanks @Bavi_H for the tip. Unfortunately, that's an inherent part of the design of the community promotion ads, so I can't personally fix it. Do you think it would make more sense if I edited the text to say "Click to learn why this matters"? (instead of "click here")

Comment: @nhinkle Sure, that seems okay.

Answer (score 26):

[image: Have Joel explain it to you.]

Comment: Basically, "copyright owners" would be able to ban a site from Google, all US traffic and all US payment services for having just a few "bad" links here and there.

Comment: Lol @ "What the hell?"

Answer (score 24):

[image: Process Hacker]

Comment: Need to change a process's I/O priority? Write garbage to its pages? Inject a DLL into it? You can do pretty much anything with this tool. :)

Comment: Is this perhaps starting to get a _bit_ redundant?

Comment: @nhinkle: Huh? Not sure what you mean...

Comment: We already have a process explorer ad, now this. I guess it's fine to have them both, I just wonder how many different process exploration software products we need to advertise. Then again, we have three blog ads, so maybe I shouldn't talk :P

Comment: @nhinkle: Oh hahaha... well IMHO this is better than process explorer :P so it's worth mentioning, but I see your point. :)

Comment: Indeed. Competition is good, even in community ads, IMHO. That's why we have an ad out for Chrome _and_ Firefox. If it weren't for this ad, I might have never found out about Process Hacker. @nhinkle

Answer (score 22):

[image: Read this week's Question of the Week, or vote for the next one on Super User Meta.]

Answer (score 20):

[image: What technology do you want to write about? The Super User Community Blog can purchase hardware and software related to blog topics. Frequent contributors also receive a free Super User T-Shirt.]

Answer (score 19):

[image: Every week, the Super User community selects an interesting question to be highlighted in the Community Blog as the "Question of the Week". Vote now on the next QotW, or submit a question you liked!]

Comment: I'm so used to seeing the vote/accept icons that I automatically mentally separated the left and right parts of this ad. Which left me wondering what "OTE" stood for.

Comment: For anyone still baffled even after reading @LordTorgamus's comment, it reads "VOTE" with a V stylized as an accept mark.

Comment: The check and "OTE" are not visually linked—in fact, the (lack of) kerning, differences in aliasing, and the vertical alignments suggests that they're *unrelated*. Even after having it explained, it's magic-eye level of hard to keep seeing the word "vote". Colour by itself isn't enough to make them visually joined.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Learn how a small amount of effort can get your question far more attention and answers!]

Answer (score 16):

[image: Xperf is important for anyone doing performance analysis on Windows, it provides a complete system-wide view over long periods of time. It fully processes all events in something that makes sense...]

Comment: **Mouse-over:** Xperf is important for anyone doing performance analysis on Windows, it provides a complete system-wide view over long periods of time. It fully processes all events in something that makes sense...

Comment: /me can't read.

Comment: @Hello71: Glad that you reverted it, or it would remain invalidated. Thank you... :-)

Answer (score 16):

[image: FreeBSD]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Daemon Tools - Virtual Blu-ray for Windows]

Comment: we shouldn't advertise paid tools

Comment: We don't.  Yes, there is a paid version of daemon tools.  There is also the free version.  That's *FREE*.  Free to download.  Free to use.

Comment: @Majenko, it's only free for non-commercial purposes.

Comment: There's always WinCDEmu, thats free and open source.

Comment: @WilliamLawnStewart And causes constant BSODs. I recommend [Virtual Clone](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html)

Comment: @kinokijuf I've never had a BSOD or any other issue from using it on various Win 7 x64 machines. That said, I haven't got the latest version, so possibly something went horribly wrong in a recent update.

Comment: @WilliamLawnStewart Yup. Trying to unmount all images in version 3.6 causes constant reboots.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Ask Different Podcast]

Comment: Upvote for linen.

Comment: The images aren't centered, or is my vision off? :P

Comment: @slhck It's not just you, the width on the left is 23px and the width on the right is 29px.

Answer (score 8):

[image: PortableApps.com: Your Digital Life, Anywhere™]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Minitube is a YouTube desktop application. With it you can watch YouTube videos in a new way: you type a keyword, Minitube gives you an endless video stream. Minitube is not about cloning the original YouTube web interface, it aims to create a new TV-like experience.]

Comment: Perhaps this needs a tagline. Personally I would never click this ad unless I had a clue to it's purpose/message/destination.

Comment: **Mouse-over:** Minitube is a YouTube desktop application. With it you can watch YouTube videos in a new way: you type a keyword, Minitube gives you an endless video stream. Minitube is not about cloning the original YouTube web interface, it aims to create a new TV-like experience.

Comment: -1 for this being a commercial product, and a whopping €9 no less (despite it being open source, apparently). See also [Should we allow commercial products in the community promotion ads?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2444/should-we-allow-commercial-products-in-the-community-promotion-ads)

Comment: @Arjan It is open-source and the only requirement for an ad is open-source and necessarily free beer.