# Community ad was locked/deleted

Tags: discussion, advertising

Just out of curiosity:

I put a link to a free-for-non-commerical-use web application I am affiliated with in the community ads section.

Now a moderator locked and deleted it telling me rules I did not read anywhere:

> Ads for services you are affiliated with - especially for commercial
>   services - are absolutely prohibited.

The application is similar to Dropbox which seems to be tolerated in the community ads section.

**My question:**

Is there kind of hidden (at least to me) policy page that states the rules and explains also why Dropbox seems to be OK?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There has been some discussion about whether ads for services that have a commercial purchase option should be permitted:

- [Define Scope of Community Promotion Ads?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2821/define-scope-of-community-promotion-ads)
- [Should we allow commercial products in the community promotion ads?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2444/should-we-allow-commercial-products-in-the-community-promotion-ads)

There has not been a definitive conclusion yet, but the general consensus is that ads for services with a commercial aspect should not be allowed. The Dropbox ad is under consideration for removal as well.

The key to why I removed your ad is that it is self promotion. [Your profile](https://superuser.com/users/11720/uwe-keim) links to your website, which is clearly for the same company that the ad promotes. [Self promotion is generally discouraged](https://superuser.com/faq#promotion) on Super User. Community Ads are supposed to be a way for the community to promote programs, projects, and events of relevance to Super Users, and which are of broad interest - *not* to promote your own products. This was the primary reason that I removed it - if you want to promote your own product, you can [purchase ads through Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact).

Comment: The Dropbox ad has been removed for the time being.