# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5996/community-promotion-ads-2013)

We're opening up the new Community Promotion Ads for Super User, in time for the upcoming year! As well, we're also changing the cycle system - these will now run on a yearly basis, not by halves.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool desktop apps
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://meta.superuser.com/ads/display/3957).

Comment: Feel free to re-add any ads that were added in the past couple months, since they didn't get much air time.

Comment: I fear that people are voting for open source projects that they like, not the ones that comply with the guidelines. The idea is supposed to be that ubiquitous projects should not feature, but some (like Fedora, FreeBSD), which are ubiquitous, are seemingly getting upvoted by fans.

Comment: Are there community ads for other Stack Exchange sites? Is there a way to find this for the other sites like StackOverflow? Simply searching for questions having "Community Promotion Ads" or that magic tag returned nothing.

Answer (score 65):

[image: Notepad++, Edit anything, anywhere, in any language]

Comment: +1 because this is what I think of when I hear "language" now at parties. "Oh, what languages do you speak, Breakthrough?"  "Oh, you know... English, C++, PHP, Python..."

Answer (score 48):

[image: Windows console emulator with tabs]

Comment: This absolutely rules! Resizable console windows sells it alone, if it wasn't for the other 200+ features.

Comment: Best Windows console I've found so far.

Answer (score 33):

[image: Your favorite apps, wherever you go.]

Comment: If you want to tinker with it, I can provide the GIMP file.

Comment: +1 I had been planning to make an advert for PortableApps ever since this was started, but I could not think of a good enough design.

Answer (score 27):

[image: If you think PuTTY was cool, try KiTTY...]

Comment: Cool, hadn't seen this before. Maybe edit it to briefly mention why it's superior to putty?

Comment: I think it should be "thought --> was" or "think --> is"

Comment: @iglvzx depends completely on what you are trying to say. The way it is now is grammatically correct. However I do agree that "thought" sounds better! I'll edit it, along with Nathan's suggestion.

Comment: @RedhattedCatsaysBestWishes If you were to choose between my two suggestions, "think -> is" would be better, advertisement-wise.

Comment: @nhinkle this better?

Comment: Awesome @RedhattedCatsaysBestWishes!

Comment: it doesn't have a scp like putty.. :(

Comment: @vineet yes it does...

Comment: @nhinkle I think one of its benefits over putty is that it can remember username and passwords for sessions

Answer (score 26):

[image: Super User members can vote on Community Ads to be displayed here. Submit yours today!]

Answer (score 25):

[image: Capture your screen the way you want it captured]

Comment: @jmendeth Ehm what?

Comment: @jmendeth Yes it IS open source... And since when is being multi-platform a requisite?

Comment: Ooops, forgot to read the `<title>`! Sorry. Undownvoting.

Comment: A project most worthy of being community advertised. Only wish it would be ported to nix, because it provides a good balance of functionality; Shutter is overcomplicated. But wait, I digress...

Answer (score 23):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: The font looks weird. Its spacing is a bit off. I would suggest to use a standard serif font (e.g. Arial, the one used here) instead, and just highlight the Twitter brand name.

Comment: I'm mostly just following a template on this one, haha. The Twitter ad is just a generic thing we use both to advert the Twitter but also as just a base demonstration of how the thread works (not sure why Super User was absent one in the previous ad thread). At any rate, if you can create any improvements, feel free to edit this image and replace it with a better one.

Comment: Haha, fair enough! Changed the font to Arial.

Comment: @GraceNote we didn't have a twitter when the last round of ads started ;)

Comment: @GraceNote: Can we have image regions? Then we can also add links to meta and chat to this ad. (｡◕‿◕｡)

Comment: Minor update: Text color and font matches Super User's h tags, uses new twitter logo, removed second twitter "logo" (it's against twitter's branding guidelines)

Comment: Oh, and [here's a PSD](http://www.mediafire.com/i/?l21nttw6g9tu9yz)

Answer (score 22):

[image: Open source, scriptable automation for Windows]

Comment: AutoHotkey's website got a facelift, so I thought I'd put this together. :)

Comment: +1 While one could say it's a common tool, many SU questions show that it's not, not enough at least.

Comment: And [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) was there first, which this is obviously copied from (but seems to have became more popular when related to hotkeys); +1 anyhow.

Comment: @TomWijsman You are never going to get off my case for preferring AHK over AutoIt, huh? :P

Comment: @iglvzx: Didn't know we spoke about AHK earlier... :(

Answer (score 20):

[image: Go Deep]

Answer (score 19):

[image: Creating PDFs just as they are supposed to be]

Comment: I'm a huge fan of PDFCreator!

Comment: @JustinDearing As am I! :D

Answer (score 19):

[image: Fedora Project]

Comment: Great Distro i use it.

Comment: I have to ask this now about each open source project: This is ubiquitous. Why is it here?

Answer (score 17):

[image: KeePass Password Storage]

Comment: Well, that's appropriate.

Comment: Needs more question mark.

Answer (score 13):

[image: It will play anything, and it'll do it for free]

> <sub>**Note:** Ads for ubiquitous software which most users are already familiar with do not [further the goals of community promotion ads](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2821/define-scope-of-community-promotion-ads). We're keeping this as an example of the types of ads that aren't constructive, but it will not actually be shown on the site.</sub>

Comment: **I don't think we need ads for popular software like VLC**. Pretty much everyone's heard of it, and if they haven't, are already using something else that does the job. See the discussion at [Define scope of community ads](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2821/define-scope-of-community-promotion-ads). What it boils down to is that VLC doesn't need our help to get attention - it's already wildly popular. We should be using community ads to promote things that aren't already so ubiquitous.

Comment: @nhinkle Great point (:

Comment: I disagree. Even though it may be ubiquitous (and I don't think it is - that's just your opinion), VLC is open source, and as such deserves everyone's support. After all, if obscureness were the defining criterion, then we would have to take down the ads for FreeBSD, Fedora and Notepad++.

Comment: @mydoghasworms I agree. However, as you can see [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2164/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011), VLC has had plenty of attention in the Community Ads program last year.

Comment: Yes, I see now, thanks. I did make a remark on the question here though, that I suspect that some ads are upvoted by fans, rather than being voted for based on their need for exposure. Anyway, it's community-driven, so I guess that's the vox populi.

Comment: Helps the project fixing http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/35

Answer (score 13):

[image: MarkdownPad is a full-featured Markdown editor for Windows.]

Comment: What does it even do?

Comment: @Richard: You'll find out when you hover over it ;) Markdown is the markup language we're using all over the SE network btw.

Answer (score 12):

[image: FreeBSD]

Comment: Good distro i use FreeNAS works reliable.

Comment: I have to ask this now about each open source project: This is ubiquitous. Why is it here?

Comment: Because the icon looks awesome (somewhat seriously, it actually doesn't look out of place), he's a daemon, and FreeBSD is not that well known, and it is rather different than Linux.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Ninite - Simple Unattended Installation and Patching]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Visit the website today!]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Mou is different: It's for web developers. Syntax highlighting, live preview, fullscreen mode, auto save, powerful actions, auto pair, incremental search, custom themes, HTML export, enhanced CJK characters support. I know, it's exactly the app you want.]

Comment: Mouseover text: Mou is different: It's for web developers. Syntax highlighting, live preview, fullscreen mode, auto save, powerful actions, auto pair, incremental search, custom themes, HTML export, enhanced CJK characters support. I know, it's exactly the app you want.

Comment: Is this open source?

Comment: No, but I don't see any requirement that states that all advertisements must be open source. Mou is free during beta, and those who donate during the beta receive a free license; Mou has been in beta for a while now.

Comment: My apologies, I believe that requirement is only on SO.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Automate repetitive tasks on your Mac with Automator]

Comment: It's surprising how often "use Automator" is a good answer to questions relating to OS X. Therefore this ad. If someone has a better URL for it, please leave a comment. http://automator.us and http://automator.tv both are ancient. http://macosxautomation.com/automator perhaps?

Comment: I think the `apple.com` link is good. It is developed by Apple, after all.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Join today!]

Comment: According to the question, "...you might promote the following things: ...anything else your community would genuinely be interested in." Because a number of Super User community members own e-book readers, I figured this would be an appropriate ad to display in the usual rotation.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Connecting to every server.]

Comment: Mouseover text: Connecting to every server.

Answer (score 1):

[image: ISO Master]

Answer (score -3):

[image: netsniff-ng - the packet sniffing beast]

Answer (score -4):

[image: Mozilla Firefox Power User Collection]

Comment: -1 Seems to mostly include well known, well established Firefox addons that don't require promotion on SU.

Comment: The requirements state "anything else your community would genuinely be interested in." As this is a one-stop shop for any firefox power user, I respectfully disagree.

Comment: @Paul I would assume a \`power user' would want to choose their own addons, not some addon \`Pack'

Comment: @Hawken, I agree with your statement and yet they can; this pack merely bookmarks all the tried and proven ones in a collection so users can find them faster. That said, it's community-driven here, so if it keeps getting downvotes then democracy rules. :)

Comment: @Paul you don't lose rep for being down-voted here right?

Comment: @Hawken No rep lost. That applies to both community wiki and meta, so...

Comment: @Hawken, correct, no rep lost. I wouldn't mind if I did as ultimately it guides people's behavior and avoids people being internet-silly--although my understanding is community wiki and meta doesn't count rep, more to avoid extra rep being added for subjective answers such as what is the best anti-virus and the like.

Answer (score -7):

[image: PortableApps.com: Your Digital Life, Anywhere™]

Comment: There's [already an ad](http://meta.superuser.com/a/3987/20088) for Portable Apps. Perhaps you could discuss with iglvzx which design will work best, and choose one to use?

Comment: @nhinkle: Sure. I'll check with the folks at PortableApps.com, too.

Answer (score -7):

[image: Liberkey]

Comment: Please read the requirements. The image must be exactly `220 x 250` pixels in dimension.

Comment: I have resized it

Comment: It is still the wrong size.

Comment: Answer needs to be only the image and link. Please follow the template that is presented in the opening post.

Comment: is this even open source?

Comment: @Stat-R No. The platform itself (LiberKey) is not open source. The applications that run on it can be.

Comment: Yes, I could not find any evidence that `Liberkey` platform  is open source

Comment: @Stat-R Perhaps you could remake the image to highlight some reasons why you would use LiberKey over PortableApps.com?

Comment: @SimonSheehan The open source requirement is only on SO.

Answer (score -8):

[image: Firefox - Take back the web]

> <sub>**Note:** Ads for ubiquitous software which most users are already familiar with do not [further the goals of community promotion ads](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2821/define-scope-of-community-promotion-ads). We're keeping this as an example of the types of ads that aren't constructive, but it will not actually be shown on the site.</sub>

Comment: Hi @Simon! Although I like a Firefox ad, I think this is a little bit too abstract. You might consider at least adding "Firefox" or something of the sort. Remember, you should be attracting people that have (little to) no experience with FF. Why should they click the ad? Just some tips, not trying to bring you down or something! :D

Comment: @RedhattedCatsaysBestWishes Great idea! thanks! I'll fix it up :)

Comment: **I don't think we need ads for popular software like Firefox**. Anybody who's on this website has heard of Firefox. See the discussion at [Define scope of community ads](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2821/define-scope-of-community-promotion-ads). What it boils down to is that Firefox doesn't need our help to get attention - it's already wildly popular. We should be using community ads to promote things that aren't already so ubiquitous.

Comment: Slowest browser still its not fastest enough with Chrome nor Opera.