# Should the StackAd WordPress plugin be used on the blog?

Tags: feature-request, superuser-blog

As requested by [studiohack](https://meta.superuser.com/users/6574/studiohack), I am opening this question to discuss the possibility of installing the [StackAd Wordpress Plugin](https://stackapps.com/questions/3102/stackad-wordpress-plugin-display-community-ads-on-your-wordpress-blog-with-min) (which I am the author of) on the [Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/).

The ads shown would be [these](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3957/community-promotion-ads-2012). Because these ads are the same ones shown on the site itself (the data is pulled directly from the question itself), I think it would be an excellent fit.

What does everyone else think?