# What is the position on people advertising their own services?

Tags: support

I've been helping with the following question:

[What limitations apply to SSL Certificates?](https://superuser.com/questions/449390/ssl-certificates-limitations/449601#comment523500_449601)

But another user has answered offering professional services. What is the feeling about this, is it allowed? Encouraged? Or should it be flagged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you feel greasier having read their post about offering services and asking you to contact them offsite instead of just giving an answer?

If so, that's most likely spam. You can flag it as spam if you feel a solicitation is happening here. That's not allowed and explicitly discouraged.

If they work on or with the product and mention their affiliation, then that's usually case-by-case depending on how they push their product in relation to answering the question. Most of the times these are allowed given the note.

For others, if they want to advertise they can either:

- Be legitimate in their posts, giving solid answers and have users check out their profile by way of natural inclination to see what work they do
- Contact Stack Exchange to pay for ads instead of using answers to trumpet their own services

Comment: Or, try their luck with a [community promotion ad](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3957/community-promotion-ads-2012) :P

Comment: Thanks guys - pretty much as I thought. The case was somewhat marginal perhaps as they did seem to be able to add something to the question. Moot point now since the answer has been removed.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg we specifically disallow self-promotion for personal gain in community ads.