# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool desktop and tablet apps
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://meta.superuser.com/ads/display/5996).

Comment: Can someone please create a community ad for [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com)? We get a lot of Ubuntu questions on SU that would get more knowledgable Ubuntu power-users/developers to look at them if they were on AU. The AU guys actually suggested to me that we do this.

Answer (score 18):

[image: Go Deep]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Super User members can vote on Community Ads to be displayed here. Submit yours today!]

Answer (score 16):

[image: Windows console emulator with tabs]

Comment: From http://meta.superuser.com/a/5023/91826

Comment: Did you know that you are awesome? :)

Answer (score 11):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Capture your screen the way you want it captured]

Comment: Wasn't there a template of some sort for this?

Comment: @slhck: What do you mean?

Comment: A PSD template for ads that look like this. Or is that your own?

Comment: @slhck: Oh, I just stole it from the previous year.

Comment: Wooh, that's mine :D

Answer (score 10):

[image: KeePass Password Safe]

Answer (score 7):

[image: SwiftSearch]

Comment: Disclaimer: I am the author. :)

Comment: Then you know that you should add some description and screen shots to the website. ,)

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Done! :)

Comment: I guess this is comparable to `Everything Search`. Would you have a link to a discussion comparing the similarities and differences between the two?

Comment: @shurane: I don't, unfortunately. Back when I made my first version (~4-5 years ago? I don't even remember anymore) I had no idea there was anything else like it, and even now, I haven't even tried Everything or UltraSearch myself yet!

Answer (score 6):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: According to the question, "...you might promote the following things: ...anything else your community would genuinely be interested in." Because a number of Super User community members own e-book readers, I figured this would be an appropriate ad to display in the usual rotation.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Debian -- The Universal Operating System]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Arch Linux: a simple, lightweight Linux distribution.]

Answer (score 5):

[image: FreeBSD]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Process Hacker]

Comment: From http://meta.superuser.com/a/2166/59271

Answer (score -4):

[image: More than creation - FreeBSD]